# Stack overflow in mutually recursive scala parser

Tags: scala, parsing

So, I'm working on this thing in scala to try to parse arithmetic expressions. I have this below where an `expr` can either be an `add` of two exprs or an `integer` constant, but it gets stuck in an infinite loop of add calling expr calling add calling expr... I'm pretty new to scala, but not to parsing. I know I'm doing something wrong, but the real question is, it it something simple?

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

abstract class Expr

case class Add(x: Expr, y: Expr) extends Expr
case class Constant(con: String) extends Expr

class Comp extends RegexParsers {

  def integer:Parser[Expr] = """-?\d+""".r ^^ {
    s => Constant(s)
  }

  def add: Parser[Expr] = expr ~ "+" ~ expr ^^ {
    case(a ~ "+" ~ b) => Add(a, b)
  }

  def expr: Parser[Expr] = (add | integer)

}

object Compiler extends Comp {

  def main(args: Array[String]) = parse(expr, "5+ -3"))//println("5+ -3")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic `RegexParsers` can't parse left-recursive grammars. To make it work, you can either modify the rule for `add` to remove left-recursiveness:

```
def add: Parser[Expr] = integer ~ "+" ~ expr ^^ {
  case(a ~ "+" ~ b) => Add(a, b)
}
```

or use [`PackratParsers`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/scala-parser-combinators/#scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers), which *can* parse such grammars:

```
class Comp extends RegexParsers with PackratParsers {

  lazy val integer:PackratParser[Expr] = """-?\d+""".r ^^ {
    s => Constant(s)
  }

  lazy val add: PackratParser[Expr] = expr ~ "+" ~ expr ^^ {
    case(a ~ "+" ~ b) => Add(a, b)
  }

  lazy val expr: PackratParser[Expr] = (add | integer)

}

object Compiler extends Comp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = parseAll(expr, "5+ -3") 
}
```

Comment: I ended up going with the second suggestion.